# Android JNI: root-causing deadd00d (dvmAbort)

Tags: android, java-native-interface

Comments on a number of StackOverflow questions have pointed out that a fault address of deadd00d indicates a deliberate VM abort.

```
I DEBUG   : signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr deadd00d
```

And indeed, when running the logs through ndk-stack, I see that the top of the stack frame decodes to:

```
Stack frame #00  pc 00050b0e  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmAbort)
```

Then the comments say to look earlier in your logs for the problem.  What exactly am I looking for -- is there a particular tag or string to search for?  (dalvikvm perhaps?)  I've scrolled through many pages of logs without finding anything relevant -- is that normal, or should it be immediately before the fault?

The deadd00d most frequently happens inside a particular call to GetObjectClass().  I've tried calling env->ExceptionCheck immediately before that line, but it doesn't report any prior errors.

I've also tried turning on CheckJNI with

```
adb shell setprop debug.checkjni 1
```

per the instructions [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/07/debugging-android-jni-with-checkjni.html) and [here](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html#extended_checking), but when killing and re-launching the app, I don't see the expected message

```
D Late-enabling CheckJNI
```

but rather

```
D AndroidRuntime: CheckJNI is OFF
```

Using `adb shell getprop` indicates that the property really is on, so I'm not sure what's going on there.

Answer (score 0):

if it is native crash,you can search "backtrace"
it will point where you native code methods crash,than you should analyze the methods,